# Creating Multi-Scene Animation using consecutive calls to Matplotlib.FuncAnimation creates flickered images

Tags: python, matplotlib-animation

**Context**: I am trying to create a teaching demo tool to show how the iteration guesses through a set of points to ultimately arrive at the root of an equation

**Problem:** I want to animate using `matplotlib` to show the iterations viusally. Specifically, given a curve (see along side) and an initial guess (say 1.5 in this particular case), I want to compose an animation of 3 scenes:

1. draw a vertical line at x = guess (=1.5), to meet the curve at y= 9 (aka value).
2. Draw a line through (guess, value) with a slope 'm' (generated by my code). Delete the vertical line at this stage and keep the second line
3. Delete the second line after a pause
   For illustration, here is the image [image]

Additionally here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
xdata2, ydata2 = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [])


def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)
    return [ln]


def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(frame ** 3 + 4 * frame ** 2 + frame - 6)
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return [ln]

def update2(frame):
    xdata2.append(1.5)
    ydata2.append(frame)
    ln.set_data(xdata2,ydata2)
    return[ln]

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(-3, 3, 100),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
ani2 = FuncAnimation(fig, update2, frames=np.linspace(0, 3, 100),blit=True)
plt.show()
```

This is a simplified version of the problem that I am trying to solve and is not part of the code that involves the calculation of the iterations etc. For now I am just trying to draw the curve in Update and post that, draw a vertical line at x=1.5.

**Results**: At my end, the entire animation is a set of flickering where it is apparent that matplotlib switches "thread context" very rapidly between the two FuncAnimation calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired animation in your next question can be achieved in the form of drawing a curve as a base graph, adding line graphs frame by frame, and deleting that graph object when necessary.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
y = x ** 3 + 4 * x **2 + x -6

xx = x[74]
yy = y[74]
#print(xx,yy)
xx2 = x[65]
yy2 = y[65]
#print(xx2,yy2)

ln, = ax.plot(x, y)
ln2, = ax.plot([], [])
ln3, = ax.plot([],[])

ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)

# Move axes center and spines off
ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
ax.spines[['left', 'bottom']].set_position('center')

# Show ticks axes only
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

def update(i):
    ln2.set_data((xx, xx), (0, yy))
    ln2.set_color('k')
    if i == 2:
        ln3.set_data((xx2, xx), (yy2, yy))
        ln3.set_color('red')
        ln3.set_width=3
    if i >=3:
        ln2.set_data([],[])
        ln3.set_data([],[])
    return ln2,ln3

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=[0,1,2,3], interval=500, blit=True, repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to render graphs in a sequence. Since, rendering a vertical line where there is no curve makes it harder to understand the relationship between the two

Comment: What you want to achieve is that you want to draw in time intervals? I don't understand what you want to do at the moment. Please indicate the main force you expect.

Comment: No, what I want to achieve is: to draw each individual curve in a sequence (one after another), and not in parallel (together).

Comment: Wow, I completely missed the updated code. Thank you @r-beginners