# Animating Newton Raphson Iteration using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am [trying to create this animation](https://miro.medium.com/max/1010/1*6Qj5chzIJBX6fnDHYzUfOg.gif) using Matplotlib animation features in Python.
Unfortunately, I am not able to figure out what would be the driving logic for keeping the main curve intact and deleting the vertical and tangential lines.

[I have made a very rudimentary try here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73464816/creating-multi-scene-animation-using-consecutive-calls-to-matplotlib-funcanimati) and failing spectacularly since I am pretty new to the animation features of matplotlib (or for that matter any other package).

How can I build this animation?